# confusion about Openam load balancer url

Tags: openam

Q1: Is there a build-in load balancer in OpenAM? 
Q2: When configuring site during installing OpenAM,I was confused about load balancer url.Is it a url for proxy like lvs/haproxy/nginx? or What it is?

Answer (score 0):

A1: No, OpenAM does not have a built-in LB

A2: the site URL can point to a VIP on a HW-LB, HTTP reverse-proxy ,etc. Apart from being a prerequisite for  SSO Session failover it 'only' controls the communication path between OpenAM client SDK based applications (like Web/J2EE agents) and OpenAM infratstructure. When configured the client SDK use the primary site URL to communicate with OpenAM infrastructure. When there is no site configured OpenAM client SDK will communicate with the 'authoritative' server of a given SSO session directly.

You don't need to configure an OpenAM site just to deploy OpenAM behind an LB or RP